# Find that the limit is $0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have to prove that the following limit is $0$:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\lvert x\rvert^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}=0.
\end{equation}

This is a part of an exercise where I have to study the differentiability of this function. I have to do it by proving that:

\begin{equation}
\Big \lvert\frac{\lvert x\rvert^2y^2}{x^2+y^4} \Big\rvert \leq \Big\lvert \cdots \Big\lvert \leq \cdots \leq\ \text{something that clearly goes  to 0} .
\end{equation}

Can you give me any ideas? I've been thinking for hours and tried almost everything but I can't see how to solve it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fact that $x^2+y^4 > 2|x|y^2$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

Then, $$\frac{\lvert x\rvert^2y^2}{x^2+y^4} \le \frac{\lvert x\rvert^2y^2}{2\lvert x\rvert y^2}=\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{2} \to 0$$

as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Better, $x^2+y^4>2|x|y^2$, otherwise there are problems when  $x<0$.

Comment: @egreg right! thanks:)

Comment: Oh god... Thank you so much! Every time that I face with a problem like this, I have troubles by trying to see what inequality use to see that limits are $0$. Is there any list of inequalities you can use or most common inequalities?

Comment: @Abrahamlure If it's a rational function in $x,y$,(like in this case) the main idea is first to compare the degrees of the polynomials in numerator and denominator and see if we can find a convenient upper/lower bound for these to squeeze it to the desired limit. Depends on the polynomials we are dealing with.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^4} \leq 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4} \leq y^2$